# can I access cookie data from a nodejs server in a reactjs application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I am trying to access the cookie data sent by my server registered in aws on my website deployed on the gh pages. I tried both on localhost and it worked well. I can access the cookie with document.cookie. But it doesn't seem to work when it's being deployed. I can see the cookies set in chrome, but document.cookie is blank.

here's my code:

```
const { origin } = req.headers;
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
return res.cookie('admin', 'true', { httpOnly: false }).send({"cookie set"});
```

```
const response = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://myserverip/session/login`,{

    headers:{     
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },
    credentials:'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    method:'POST', 
    });
    console.log(await response.json());
    if(response.status === 200){
      console.log(document.cookie);
    }
```

Comment: By default, a cookie is accessible only at the domain that set it. Here the cookie is set by `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`. Is your page hosted on the same domain?

Comment: no, i use this proxy because my server is http and ghpages is https. but regardless, when I try to access my server on the aws of my page on localhost, I see the same problem (fetch from localhost to aws without proxy). But I put them together in the same domain in aws and there I can access the cookie ... In localhost->aws i can see cookies in chrome devtools but no value in document.cookie